# @Autowired is null with jax ws + Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jax-ws, autowired

The @Autowired annotated class variable is comming as Null. jax ws web service has used Spring Boot and Endpoint for implementation.

Comment: you should show your code.

Answer (score -1):

Try to see if you have missed a `@Component` or an `@Service` annotation in the class you want to autowire.
Also have a look here: 
[Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null?rq=1)